# Why can't 'locate' or 'find' find 'makeinfo'?

Tags: find, locate

When I do:

```
locate makeinfo
```

OR

```
find / -name "*makeinfo*"
```

I get nothing.

But when I do `makeinfo --help`, it gives me the proper help output.

How is this possible? If `makeinfo` is an executable, it must be located *somewhere*, correct? Or it can be an alias, which it isn't. I check `.bashrc`, `.bash_aliases` and all those files. I can't imagine how this can occur.

What are the reasons for this weird behavior?

Edit: `type makeinfo` and `which makeinfo` both output `/usr/bin/makeinfo`.

Comment: What is the output of `type makeinfo` ?

Comment: `makeinfo` is normally located at `/usr/bin/makeinfo`. `locate makeinfo` gives me `/usr/bin/makeinfo`. What is your distribution? How do you have `texinfo` installed? What does `which makeinfo` give you?

Comment: Please post the output of `type -a makeinfo`.

Comment: @JohnRed you can delete it

Comment: @roaima I could, but I find that whatever I write, I think of it as "content" or "knowledge". I don't like to delete such created content, however crude it may be. It may be that others think the same. What are my alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

It seems that `locate` is fast because it relies upon a database it builds to search for things faster. This database is updated daily. The `updatedb` command does this. As it turns out, `updatedb` is run every 24 hours, and 24 hours hadn't passed when I tried to search for the file using `locate`, from the time the file was created. After running `sudo updatedb`, locate was able to find the file.

I suggest reading the manpages of `locate` and `updatedb` for more information.

As for `find`, it seems I was impatient and did not wait for it to finish to its execution.

Answer (score -1):

I don't use or know much about 'locate(1)'. But 'find(1)' may be failing to find your command because it does not by default cross filesystem lines. The makeinfo command is likely in /usr/bin (type `which makeinfo` to find it), and the '/usr' partition may be on another filesystem.

EDIT: Doh! I see the problem! do not use "*makeinfo*". Use 'makeinfo'. If you really want to find a file that has the string 'makeinfo' somewhere in it, use: `find / -type f -name '*makeinfo*'`. That is, only compare against files (not directories -- much faster), and use single quotes, not double quotes.

Final EDIT: My answer was /way/ off. His problems were unrelated to double-quotes.

Comment: `find` usually crosses fs borders, that's why it has `-xdev` option.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. My apologies, as I got it backwards. In that case, 'find' should indeed find your command. Let's see the output of `which makeinfo` then!

Comment: What is the difference? I had always assumed that single quotes and double quotes are the same in bash.

Comment: No, single and double quotes are the same in python (more or less), but no in any shell I know of.  Double quotes tell the shell you want to expand a pathname or filename, and single quotes tell the shell you mean to pass in exactly what you passed in. In this case, you need to use single quotes to pass the asterisks to the find command, so that /it/ can interpret your request, rather than letting the shell do it.

Comment: Double quotes prevent path expansion as well -- see: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Double-Quotes for e.g. bash

Comment: @Lee-Man: (0) The very first shell (40 years ago, long before the Bourne shell) treated the two quote characters the same.  As soon as people started writing shell scripts, this was discovered to be a serious shortcoming (i.e., a real pain), and it was quickly fixed.  (1) You’re right that single and double quotes are different, and that the meaning of single quotes can be characterized as “you mean to pass in exactly what you passed in.”  But double quotes do not mean that “you want to expand a pathname or filename” in any common shell;  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  try `echo *`, `echo '*'`, and `echo "*"`, and you’ll see that single and double quotes behave the same in these cases. The main difference is in the handling of shell variables.  If you define a variable `today="May 19"`, then `ls -l '$today'` looks for a file literally called `$today`, `ls -l "$today"` looks for a file called `May 19`, and `ls -l $today` looks for two files: one called `May` and one called `19` (the same as if you had typed `ls -l May 19`).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) For `find`, comparing a filename to a pattern is a fairly simple test.  I doubt that `find / -type f -name '*makeinfo*'` will be “much faster” than `find / -name "*makeinfo*"` — especially when the latter is yielding no results.

Comment: @G-Man, you are of course correct. I should have tested my theory and response before posting it. But using "-type f" _is_ faster by a bit. A quick local test on a large filesystem shows that using "-type f" cut about 2% of the time it takes to locate matching files.